# Can I create Java-like interfaces in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop, interface, object, abstract

I understand that Perl's OO model is rather primitive;  it is, in most respects, essentially a namespace hack.

Nevertheless, I wonder if it is possible to create something like an "interface?"  My goal is to have a base class from which others are extended whose principal purpose is to make mandatory the implementation of certain methods (by name is fine, no signature necessary) by those subclasses.  I don't really care if it's a "purely virtual" class (like an "interface" in Java) or a concrete class with actual implementational stubs for those methods in the superclass, but what I want is to make it deterministically necessary that the subclass implement certain methods of the superclass.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Perl's OO isn't primitive, it's just a different way of approaching the concept.

Comment: I think he meant primitive in terms of features offered.  OO has a few guiding principles, and encapsulation is one of them.  Perl is doing (most of the time) encapsulation by convention, unless one uses the more modern libraries, so yes, Perl's OO is primitive, relying on the future developers to maintain the convention instead of strict compile time checking.  I mean, this person is asking for interface / pure virtual classes, and it's not there without extensions.  That's not "fully featured".

Comment: Another one: I found Ben Tilly's [AbstractClass](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=44300) on PerlMonks.  I don't see it on CPAN, but it's only one file, so it's easy to copy/paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the whole idea of mandating implementation/overloading of base class's functions/subs is foreign to Perl. At which point would you envision the enforcement mechanism working?

If you're OK with doing this at runtime, you can die if your base class's implementation gets called.

EDIT: Actually, yes, Class::Contract seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 30):

Here's an answer using [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) ...

```
package Comparable;
use Moose::Role;

requires 'eq';

package Person;

has size => (
    is   => 'ro',
    does => 'Comparable',
);
```

Now the size attribute must be an object which implements the Comparable "interface". In Moose-land, interfaces are roles, and roles can be more than just an interface definition.

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure how you will be able to implement it. However, have a look at [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose), which is "A postmodern object system for Perl 5".

- [Moose::Manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Manual)
- [Moose::Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Cookbook)

Comment: With Moose, roles can perform the function of a Java interface. They can also do more, but a role that just has a list of required methods is an interface.

Answer (score 6):

The [Class::Contract](http://search.cpan.org/~ggoebel/Class-Contract-1.14/lib/Class/Contract/Production.pm) can help with this. It supports compile-time contract checking.

Answer (score 2):

I have a lightweight pattern I call "Compatible", and I discuss it in my answer to [How important is it to indicate if a class implements an interface in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310105/how-important-is-it-to-indicate-if-a-class-implements-an-interface-in-perl#answer-310471)

It's just a matter of sticking pseudo packages in `@ISA`:

```
our @ISA = qw<... X::Compatible ...>;
```

You break their code if you don't do what they expect from `X`. In practice I have a bunch of documented behaviors that I reuse, but a class telling me it's `X::Compatible` is what I use to assure myself that it can do what I expect.

Since perl 5.10 has introduced the `DOES` concept, which is about as lightweight, a `X::Compatible` object inherits from a base class `Object::Compatible` which implements a base `DOES` by looking through `@ISA` for `/::Compatible$/` and replying to the affirmative for anything in there. The idea is that:

```
$object->DOES( $x ) == $object->isa( $x . '::Compatible' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution that creates errors at runtime:

```
package SomeVirtualClass;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp;

sub some_method { croak "virtual method some_method not overridden" }
```

Comment: Well, yes, no doubt this is a possibility.  To be perfectly honest, though, I was looking for something on a more semantic level.