# Java interface equivalent in Perl

Tags: perl, interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I create Java-like interfaces in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072439/can-i-create-java-like-interfaces-in-perl)

How the Java like interfaces is supported in Perl?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose), you could create [role](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aRole) with nothing but a `requires` statement.